# Is it possible to change the background color of the tmux pane or window?

Tags: linux, tmux

I would like different panes to appear in different background colors in my tmux session.
Is this possible?

Comment: Good answers already submitted.  Note that you can make changes from the command line.  The TMUX_PANE variable can identify different panes.  Pres s the command key (Ctrl-B), a colon, and type "set -g " as StefanS suggests.  e.g., Ctrl-B then ":set -g pane-active-border-bg magenta".  Since his example and mine differ, maybe there  are differences in tmux.  Use "man tmux" and search for "colour".  (Yeah, I'm American, but my copy of the man page has a "u" in the word.  So search for colour, not color.)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25532773/change-background-color-of-active-or-inactive-pane-in-tmux

Answer (score 23):

You can set any pane's style using the `select-pane -P` command.
You can combine this with other select-pane options for example

```
select-pane -t:.1 -P 'bg=red'
```

would set the first pane's background as red.

```
select-pane -P 'bg=red'
```

would set the current pane's background to red.

Comment: If anyone is wondering what `-P` stands for in this context, I think the answer is nothing in particular. In other places in tmux syntax, a "p" flag might stand for "parent", "pane" or "print", but none of those apply here, were "-P" is used to a set a style and it's "-t" that selects the pane.

Comment: This is super nice - I use it to mark a pane as "root" (red or bright background color)  if it has creds that are above norm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no obvious way to do it. I did a bit of research on the matter and what I ended up doing was changing the BASH prompt color instead of the background color. In my case it works well and helps me identify the different panes at a glance. Here are the two most helpful pages that I found on the subject:

[Change The Color of My Shell Prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/)

[Cnange shell background color on ssh](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1379279)

I hope this helps you on your quest for knowledge :-)

Comment: Synopsizing the content of those linked documents would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your colors in your `~/.tmux.conf.` You could specify colours like so:

```
# border colours

 set -g pane-border-style fg=magenta
 set -g pane-active-border-style fg=magenta 
 set -g pane-active-border-style bg=default
```

Answer (score 0):

[tmux-session-spectrum](https://github.com/a-rodin/tmux-session-spectrum) provides a way to do this for tmux sessions:

```
 git clone https://github.com/a-rodin/tmux-session-spectrum  \
  "${HOME}/.tmux/plugins/tmux-session-spectrum"
```

In `~/.tmux-conf`:

```
set-hook -g after-new-session "run-shell 'bash ~/.tmux/plugins/tmux-session-spectrum/tmux-session-spectrum.sh'"
```

This can be tweaked to run per-pane instead of per-session.

Comment: Can you describe the 'tweak' you would make to cause this to work on a per-pane basis?  The plug-in itself only talks about changing the status bar from session to session.